# Convert string column to DateTime format

Tags: python, string, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame column where value is of string type 'June 6, 2016, 6' and I want to convert it into DataTime as 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM' format.

When tried convert by just taking value , I could able to convert it into right format.

```
import datetime
stringDate = "June 6, 2016, 11"
dateObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(stringDate, "%B %d, %Y, %H")
print dateObject

**Output : 2016-06-06 11:00:00**
```

But when I tried different options to apply the same conversion on python dataframe columns I'm not getting time part in the conversion.

```
**Option1**
df['Date'] = df.Date.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%B %d, %Y, %H").date())

**Option2**
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] = df.Date.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%B %d, %Y, %H"))
```

**Output: both cases got 2016-06-06**

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `format` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print (pd.to_datetime('June 6, 2016, 11', format='%B %d, %Y, %H'))
2016-06-06 11:00:00
```

It works with `DataFrame` too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['June 6, 2016, 11', 'May 6, 2016, 11']})
print (df)
               Date
0  June 6, 2016, 11
1   May 6, 2016, 11

print (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%B %d, %Y, %H'))
0   2016-06-06 11:00:00
1   2016-05-06 11:00:00
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: `Thanks for the reply.